# Entity Framework : the data in dbContext is updated but not in the database

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS9mU.jpg)

The proplem is when  I insert a row to a table in dbcontext, but that row isn't inserted to the database.
Firstly, I think that my code is not run, but when i use the unit test [see in the picture], the testcase `PostCategory_Repository_Create` is passed, that means the data inserted, and it return `Id` "1". Then I run that testcase again, and the `Id` is became to "2" (this is because the "Id" field is identity). 
But the data just has updated on the dbcontext, not in database....why??
please, many thanks.

Comment: Can we see the code? Are you calling SaveChanges() ?

Comment: sure i call it,

Answer (score 0):

this is the code of class UniOfWork, i use repository design pattern :

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDbFactory dbFactory;
    private ShopDbContext dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }
    public ShopDbContext DbContext
    {
        get { return dbContext ?? (dbContext = dbFactory.Init()); }
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you call SaveChanges() on DbContext instead of dbContext? is this a copy/paste error?

Comment: Also, please update your question rather than pasting in the answer ( unless you are answering your own question)